# How to render file-based template with arguments?

Tags: python, mako

```
from mako.template import Template

stext = "hi"

mytemplate = Template(filename='./t.txt')
print mytemplate.render()
```

t.txt:

```
${hi}  , i am here
```

Comment: Relative paths are Usually Wrong when it comes to web stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the last line with:

```
mytemplate.render(hi = "world")
```

Now, `hi` can equal anything you like, not just `"world"`.

Comment: where does that happen? On waht line?

Comment: i find it must be "hi = stext"

Comment: I see, I'm sorry for the confusion. Here's some documentation: http://www.makotemplates.org/